# Deserializing a JSON object within a JSON Object

Tags: api, apexrest

I have am trying to deserialize a JSON object within a JSON Object, what I am wondering is do I have to deserialize the response twice somehow?

Does anyone have any examples of how to do this? 
What I am trying to get out of the sample below is the two uuids. One is the in the main response body and the second is layered in a location object.

```
{
  "link": {
    "url": "https://api.fieldaware.net/customer/4d18011294364a85a1c5541b9b4a0eee",
    "rel": "detail"
  },
  "location": {
    "link": {
      "url": "https://api.fieldaware.net/location/3b0fd4f427ac47bfa02c956a8f3179c9",
      "rel": "detail"
    },
    "uuid": "4a1de64d6b184abfb5692d2443dfa4d2",
  },
  "uuid": "3b0fd4f427ac47bfa02c956a8f3179c9",
  "email": "user10@glidebooks.com",
  "firstName": "Blaise",
  "lastName": "Champlin",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "phone": null,
  "platform": "ios",
  "role": "Admin",
  "timezone": "Europe/Dublin",
  "customFields": {},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have posted is not valid [JSON](http://json.org/) because of extra trailing commas before a couple of closing `}`. If that is just a cut and paste error, you can parse the JSON conventionally e.g. using the code generated by [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/). The [JSON.deserialize](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) method used by that generated code will handle nested objects automatically.